# Use vuelidate from node_modules in django template

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I've used Vue to consume an API but never in Django templates. I'd like to use the [`Vuelidate`](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#getting-started) package for form validation but I'm having some problems importing `validationMixin` as specified in their documentation: `import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'`.

I'm currently importing Vue.js from a CDN.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

I'm adding the path to vuelidate to my static files.

```
# settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'node_modules', 'vuelidate', 'dist'),
]
```

When my Django template is loaded I get `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` (Firefox) and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` (Chrome)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'vuelidate.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
    const app = new Vue({
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            test: 'Hello'
        }
    })
</script>
```

I added `type="module"` to the script tag but that results in `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: vuelidate` (Firefox) and `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vuelidate". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` (Chrome)

What am I missing here?

Comment: try add `type="module"` and do `import { validationMixin } from './vuelidate.min.js'`

Comment: @Ja9ad335h I'm getting a 404 because path isn't coming from the static folder it's coming from `http://localhost:8000/url_path/vuelidate.min.js`

Comment: what is the rendered `src` on browser for `src="{% static 'vuelidate.min.js' %}"`

Comment: @Ja9ad335h `http://localhost:8000/static/vuelidate.min.js`

Comment: and what is `url_path` in `http://localhost:8000/url_path/vuelidate.min.js`? you can use relative paths to import like `from '../../vuelidate.min.js'`